# How to remove default pagination in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am using aws sdk to query through a dynamo table

```
   const dynamodbClient = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
        region: 'region,
        
      })
```

and the query is

```
dynamodbClient
        .query({
          TableName: 'table-n',
          IndexName:'orgId-index',
          KeyConditionExpression: 'orgId = :orgId',
          ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':orgId': 'abc',
          },
        })
```

and i have GSI `'orgId-index'` with the partition key in ordId field.

I have a huge data set in my table, i.e about 250000 and there can be a cases here where the 25k users have the same orgId

What i want is to get all these 25k data point at the same time

But his query returns just 12 records and returns a additional `LastEvaluatedKey` by default. I have not added any pagination params.

Also if i use this query in annother table with 80 records. All the records are returned at once without pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB pagination is not optional.  The response to query and scan requests is limited to 1MB.  If your operation returns more than that, your results will be paginated.